# php query function repeating data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to make a facebook style chat page using php and mysql. But i have a problem with my query result. The chat table looks like this.

[image]

And i write this function for getting the message for loged in user.

```
/*Get Messges*/
public function Get_Messages($toid,$logedInUserID){
   // Here is loged in user id the id is 2
   $logedInUserID = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db,$logedInUserID);
   // Loged in user id talked with $toid before the id is 3
   $toid = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db,$toid);
   $logedInUserID = '2';  
   $toid = '3';

   $query = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT DISTINCT C.msg_id,C.from_user_id, C.to_user_id, C.message_created_time, C.message_text, U.user_name, U.user_fullname FROM users U, chat C WHERE C.from_user_id='$logedInUserID' AND C.to_user_id = '$toid' ORDER BY C.msg_id ASC LIMIT 20") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // Store the result into array
        $data[]=$row;
     }
     if(!empty($data)) {
        // Store the result into array
        return $data;
     }
}
```

and the foreachloop for getting result

```
<?php 
    $GetAllMessages = $Get->Get_Messages($toUserID,$uid);
     if($GetAllMessages){
         echo '<span class="all_messages">';
      foreach($GetAllMessages as $getMessage){
         $getTexts = $getMessage['message_text']; 
         $getToUID = $getMessage['to_user_id']; 
         $from_to_class= 'you';
         if($getToUID == $uid){
             $from_to_class = 'friend';
         } 
         echo '<div class="messageBox_body"><div class="'.$from_to_class.'">'.$getTexts.'</div></div>';
       }
         echo '</span>';
      } 
?>
```

So the problem is my query repeating the messages like the following screenshot also the query not showing loged in user messages.

To be a little more descriptive:

```
$logedInUserID = '2';
$toid = '3';
```

The query showing `$toid = '3';` messages with repeat and not showing `$logedInUserID = '2';` from data.

What is the problem in my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.msg_id,C.from_user_id, C.to_user_id, C.message_created_time, 
C.message_text, U.user_name, U.user_fullname FROM users U, chat C WHERE 
C.from_user_id='$logedInUserID' AND C.to_user_id = '$toid' 
ORDER BY C.msg_id ASC LIMIT 20
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, in given query it seems that your are trying to fetch details from two table User and Chat, however you have not written join condition.

Comment: @SonamTripathi Can you explain me within query please.

Comment: Please check in answer. Do let me know if any concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In given query it seems that you are trying to fetch details from two table **User** and **Chat**, however you have not written join condition.

Please try this SQL query, with $logedInUserID = '2'; $toid = '3';

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.msg_id, 
                C.from_user_id, 
                C.to_user_id, 
                C.message_created_time, 
                C.message_text, 
                U.user_name, 
                U.user_fullname 
FROM   users U 
       JOIN chat C 
         ON U.id = C.from_user_id 
WHERE  C.from_user_id = '$logedInUserID' 
       AND C.to_user_id = '$toid' 
ORDER  BY C.msg_id ASC 
LIMIT  20
```

If you want entire chat with both user just use "OR" condition in Sql query with interchanged $logedInUserID = '3'; $toid = '2'